# Why is array_search not finding, unless array is sorted?

Tags: php, php-5.4

I'm having trouble understanding the result of [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) in the following example (and did not find any existing questions discussing this):

```
<?php

    $values = array(
        15,
        12,
        "15",
        34,
        15 => 25,
        "xx" => 15
    );
    echo "PHP-Version is " . phpversion();
    echo "<h1>Array:</h1><pre>";var_dump($values);echo "</pre>";    

    // sort($values); // remove comment and 15 will be found in ALL cases!

    $key = array_search("15",$values);
        show_result('(a) Searching "15"');

    $key = array_search("15",$values,true);
        show_result('(b) Searching "15",true');

    $key = array_search(15,$values);
        show_result('(c) Searching 15');

    $key = array_search(15,$values,false);
        show_result('(d) Searching 15,false');

    $key = array_search(15,$values,true);
        show_result('(e) Searching 15,true');



function show_result($tit) {    
    global $key,$values;
    echo "<h2>$tit</h2>";

    if (!$key) { 
        echo "Not found";
        } else {
            echo "Found key $key - " . gettype($values[$key]);
    }
}
?>
```

Only search (b) - the strict string-search finds the value, numeric search does not find it. All searches do find it when the array is sorted - but the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) does not mention such a requirement at all. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: if($key===false) because index 0 is also false.

Comment: For once the OP already read the manual. Too bad you didn't read it in its entirety. ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `15` is at key `0`. `array_search` returns this `0`. `0` evaluates to `false`. Your check `if (!$key)` therefore fails for the key `0`. You have to check for strict `=== false`. There's a giant red warning in [the manual](http://www.php.net/array_search) explaining this.

Comment: Thank you - I was so focused on the array that I did not pay enough attention to the type of the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the return value of `array_search` is a mixed value. When you perform the first search it will find the value at position `0` and therefor return the keys index which in turn will be evaluated to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the total explaination:

In all your cases, $key equals to 0, and since you are doing a simple test like `if($key)` 0 evaluates to false making you think that the search was not succesful. Changing it to `if($key===false)` will work without any problem.

The reason why it works without any problem when you sort the array is because the value 12 is inside so it takes the key 0 and the 15 that was at key 0 is now at key 1 and 1 evaluates to `true`.